# Clone dependent/cascading/dynamic select dropdown - Flask WTF

Tags: javascript, flask, wtforms

I am developing a Flask application where I manage cascading drop down forms with WTF ( example clients / accounts, treasury bonds / ISIN code ). I've adapted my template so that the cascading (or dependent) selects works fine. Problem is when I duplicate the form fields with this  repeater : https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater , the fields on the duplicate are no longer dependent - I have an empty dependent select as shown in the images below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zpI7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNJIH.png)

Any help ? thank you !

The form :

```
class TransacTbonds(FlaskForm):

bondname1 = SelectField('BTA1:', validators=[DataRequired()] )
isin1 = SelectField('Code ISIN1:', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

htlm :

```
    <!--begin::Form group-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div data-repeater-list="kt_ecommerce_add_product_options" class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
            <div data-repeater-item="" class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center gap-5">
                <!--begin::Select2-->
                <div class="w-100 w-md-200px">
                    <select class="form-select name" name="product_option" data-placeholder="Select a variation" data-kt-ecommerce-catalog-add-product="product_option" >
                        <option></option>
                        {% for bta in TbondnameIsin %}
                            <option> {{ bta['secname'] }}  </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-select isin" name="product_option1" data-placeholder="Select a variation" data-kt-ecommerce-catalog-add-product="product_option1" >
                        <option></option>
                        {% for bta in TbondnameIsin %}
                            <option> {{ bta['isincode'] }}  </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                </div>
                <!--end::Select2-->
                <!--begin::Input-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control mw-100 w-200px" name="product_option_value" placeholder="Variation" />
                <!--end::Input-->
                <button type="button" data-repeater-delete="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-light-danger">

....

<button type="button" data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn-sm btn-light-primary">Add another form</button>
```

JS :

```
var CascadingFormRepeater = function () {

    var form;

    var dropdown = {
        tbondname: $('select').closest('.w-100').find('.name'),
        tbondisin: $('select').closest('.w-100').find('.isin')
    };

    // call to update on load
    updateISIN();

    // function to call XHR and update ISIN dropdown
    function updateISIN() {
        var send = {
            tbondname: dropdown.tbondname.val()
        };
        dropdown.tbondisin.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        dropdown.tbondisin.empty();
        $.getJSON("isinselect", send, function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                dropdown.tbondisin.append(
                    $('<option>', {
                        value: item[0],
                        text: item[1]
                    })
                );
            });

            dropdown.tbondisin.removeAttr('disabled');
            //dropdown.tbondname.removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    }

    // event listener to state dropdown change
    $(document).on('change', '.name', function() {
        updateISIN();
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.isin' , function() {
          updateISIN();
     });

    const initFormRepeater = () => {
        $('#kt_ecommerce_add_product_options').repeater({

            isFirstItemUndeletable: true,

            initEmpty: false,

            defaultValues: {
                'text-input': 'foo'
            },

            show: function () {
                // Init select2 on new repeated items
                $(this).slideDown();

                // Attach event listener to tbondname select fields in new form repeater row

                $(this).find('.name').on('change',function () {
                    
                    updateISIN();

                });
                // second select field is bank and disabled
                $('select')
                    //.select2("destroy");
                    .removeAttr('disabled'); //




                // Init select2 on new repeated items
                initConditionsSelect2();
            },

            hide: function (deleteElement) {
                $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
            },

        });
    }

    const initConditionsSelect2 = () => {
        // Init new repeating condition types
        const allConditionTypes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-kt-ecommerce-catalog-add-product="product_option"] [data-kt-ecommerce-catalog-add-product="product_option1"]');
        
        allConditionTypes.forEach(type => {

            if ($(type).hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                return;
            } else {
                $(type).select2({
                    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
                });
            }


        });
    }



   // Public methods
    return {
        init: function(element) {
            form = document.querySelector('#kt_invoice_form');

            initFormRepeater();
            initConditionsSelect2();
            //handeForm();
            //updateTotal();
        }
    };




}();

KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded(function () {
    CascadingFormRepeater.init();
});
```

I also tried to duplicate the form with cloneNode method but still having problems with select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally sorted this out not with the form repeater but by cloning the table and the dependent dropdown select, here is my workaround:

The html:

```
<table class="table g-5 gs-0 mb-0 fw-bold text-gray-700" data-kt-element="items">
    ....
    <button class="btn btn-link py-1" data-kt-element="add-item">Add item</button>
</table>


<table class="table d-none" data-kt-element="item-template">
    <tr class="border-bottom border-bottom-dashed" data-kt-element="item">
        <td class="pe-7">
            <select class="form-select form-select-solid mb-2 name1" data-placeholder="BTA">
                <option></option>
                    {% for bta1 in TbondnameIsin1 %}
                <option> {{ bta1['secname'] }} </option>
                    {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <select class="form-select form-select-solid mb-2 isin1" data-placeholder="ISIN">
                <option></option>
                    {% for bta1 in TbondnameIsin1 %}
                <option> {{ bta1['isincode'] }} </option>
                    {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JS :

```
form.querySelector('[data-kt-element="items"] [data-kt-element="add-item"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // find the 'items' table body element
    var itemsTable = form.querySelector('[data-kt-element="items"] tbody');
    // add event listener to the 'items' table body element
    itemsTable.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // check if the change event was triggered by a select element with the class 'name1'
    if (e.target.classList.contains('name1')) {
    // find the corresponding 'isin1' element for the current row
    var isin1 = e.target.closest('tr').querySelector('.isin1');
    // call the function to update the 'isin1' dropdown
    addupdateISIN(e.target.value, isin1);
    }
    });
    // Clone table rows
    var item = form.querySelector('[data-kt-element="item-template"] tr').cloneNode(true);
    itemsTable.appendChild(item);
     // Call select2() function on the new select element
    $(item).find('.name1').select2();
    // Call select2() function on the new select element
    $(item).find('.isin1').select2();
    // define an object called 'dropdown' with two properties
    var dropdown = {
        tbondname1: $(item).find('.name1'), 
        tbondisin1: $(item).find('.isin1')
    };
    // call to update on load
    addupdateISIN(dropdown.tbondname1.val(), dropdown.tbondisin1);
    // add an event listener to the 'tbondname1' dropdown that calls the 'addupdateISIN()' function when the selected value changes
    dropdown.tbondname1.on('change', function() {
    addupdateISIN($(this).val(), dropdown.tbondisin1);
    });
    // function to call XHR and update county dropdown
    function addupdateISIN(tbondname1, tbondisin1) {
        // disable the 'tbondisin1' dropdown
        tbondisin1.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        // empty the 'tbondisin1' dropdown
        tbondisin1.empty();
        // GET request to the server using the 'send' object, and update the 'tbondisin1' dropdown based on the response
        $.getJSON('addisinselect', { tbondname1: tbondname1 }, function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                tbondisin1.append(
                    $('<option>', {
                        value: item[0], // set the 'value' attribute of the <option> element to the first element of the current item in the response array
                        text: item[1] // set the text content of the <option> element to the second element of the current item in the response array
                    })
                );
            });
        // re-enable the 'tbondisin1' dropdown
            tbondisin1.removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    }
});
```

Reminder, I use Flask WTF to manage the form.